# Button Cooldown Timer

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I am making a game and I want to have the player travel forward and high speeds (turbo) when the player presses <kbd>E</kbd> but I want there to be a cooldown timer so you can't rapidly press <kbd>E</kbd> and go way too fast. I don't know python and I don't plan on learning it anytime soon. A solution with python would work, but I would really prefer one with logic bricks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very easy to do. This is the same method you would use if you were creating a reload property for a gun. Create an integer property name *Time* that is always increasing as long as that property is less than 100. In this case, it is named *time*, Of course you could name it whatever you wanted.

[image]

Then have another property sensor limiting the keyboard's input so that it will only send a positive pulse when the integer *Time* is equal to 100 **And** <kbd>E</kbd> is pressed.

When using a system like this, you can hammer on the keyboard as fast as you want, but it will only turbo when the property *Time* reaches 100. and as soon as you turbo, The time property starts increasing until it reaches 100, where you will be ready to turbo again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this was a HUGE help. But is there a way I can make it so when the play is facing the opposite direction he will go that way? So I have it set to when you press E you will move really quickly along the +X axis. But I want it so when the player is facing left on the -X axis he will move that way. I cannot turn the player movement controller or the controls get inverted. I tried making a new object and having it track towards empties and attach the logic bricks to that but it did not work.

Comment: If it helped, feel free to Upvote and accept. (the little grey circle with the check mark in it.) You will also get two reputation fro accepting it.

Comment: Depending on how complicated your system is, You could just have a Boolean property toggle the direction of movement, and depending if it toggles to true or false, It would turbo different directions. - It would be easier for you to ask another question than for me to try to tell you how to do it in a comment :-)